# Vague Khanacademy explanation

Tags: statistics

[image]

The above fictitious dot plot has fifty dots - representing the percentage of ontime flights (on x-axis) for fifty popular airlines. We're to identify the correct comment on the given dot plot. I couldn't grasp how to do it at all, the option D is cited as correct. The given explanation is very vague in terms of "pull"s and I couldn't connect it at all to anything worth understanding.

Can anyone please explain to me how fewer points far from the central region affect the mean more than they do the median?

And are there other patterns as to when they affect the median more, or both equally, or other such?

Comment: I am not sure if this is satisfactory, but you might try computing the mean and the median of the sets $(1,1000,1001)$ and $(1,2,1000)$ and comparing them as an exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For perfectly symmetric data the mean and the median coincide. For instance, take the set $S_1 = \{1,3,5,7 \}$. The mean and the median of this set of data are both $4$.

Now, imagine adding a value to $S_1$ that is far from this central value, say, $20$. The new data set is $S_2 = \{1,3,5,7,20 \}$. It should be fairly obvious, even before doing any calculations, that the mean for $S_2$ is going to be much higher than the mean for $S_1$ due to the presence of the number $20$, which is much higher than most of the other values. Likewise, it is also clear that the median is not going to change very much since we have only added one number far from the center, and the median actually doesn't care about the value of the number like the mean does (i.e. it would make no difference to the median if we had added $20$ versus adding $200$).

Indeed, carrying out the calculations we find that the mean of $S_2$ is $7.2$ and the median of $S_2$ is $5$. The number $20$, which is far to the right of the center, has pulled the mean significantly to the right yet has little effect on the median. You may argue that the change in the median here can be considered significant as well, but just realize that I am working with a very small data set. When there are more data points clustered around the central region (as in your problem) the median is likely to not even change at all with the addition of a few outlying points, but the mean will still be affected.

So, the point is, values far from the central region tend to pull the mean toward them, since the mean is very sensitive to outliers. The median, however, is less affected by values far from the central region. As a result, the median is generally a better measure of center for highly skewed data. Just think of the set $S_2$ above. Would you say that most of the values cluster around $5$ or around $7.2$? I would rather say $5$.

Comment: Thanks for your long answer!